# Laravel 5 - how to use basic auth with username in place of email?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, basic-authentication, laravel-middleware

Hello guys !

So in Laravel 4 we could do

```
Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic('username');
});
```

But now it's not possible, and the doc doesn't give a clue about how to. So can anyone help ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a new custom middleware using the same code as the default one:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/AuthenticateWithBasicAuth.php

and override the default 'email' field like:

```
return $this->auth->basic('username') ?: $next($request);
```

Comment: Yes that's what I thought... So nothing better  than that eh... Thanks :)

Comment: thanks. Really I couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation

Answer (score 7):

Using Laravel 5.7, the handle method looks like this:

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @param  string|null  $field
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null, $field = null)
{
    return $this->auth->guard($guard)->basic($field ?: 'email') ?: $next($request);
}
```

If you look at the function definition, can specify the `$field` value.

[According to Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#middleware-parameters) you can provide middleware parameters:

> Middleware parameters may be specified when defining the route by separating the middleware name and parameters with a :. Multiple parameters should be delimited by commas:

Using the following I was able to specify my field to use in basic auth:

```
Route::middleware('auth.basic:,username')->get('/<route>', 'MyController@action');
```

The `:,username` syntax might be a little confusing. But if you look at the function definition:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null, $field = null)
```

You will notice there are two paramters after `$next`. `$guard` is `null` by default and I wanted it remain null/empty so I omit the value and provide an empty string. The next parameter (separated by a comma like the documentation says) is the `$field` I'd like to use for basic auth.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using

```
class AuthenticateOnceWithBasicAuth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return Auth::onceBasic('username') ?: $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to copy all the code: You also can add this directly to the route like this: `'auth.basic:,username'`. Then, instead of the e-mail, the basic auth will use the username. So, you will end up with something like this: `Route::middleware('auth.basic:,username')`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).